# How to Connect To AWS ElasticSearch Instance from Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, logstash, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to grant access to my AWS ElasticSearch instance from my Elastic Beanstalk (Ruby on Rails) app. Specifically, I am attempting to pipe logstash data via the `logstash-elasticsearch` plugin. My expectation was that this would be a standard use-case (based upon [this blog post](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/elasticbeanstalk-elk-stack-ef92f4e295c1#.r5r792s8z)), but it appears impossible.

The first thing I tried was setting an access policy on the ES instance for the EB role:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-1:XXXXX:domain/YYYY/*"
    }
```

This did not work, I believe because of the port which is used to communicate between the EC2 instance and ES. Other options I've considered:

- Grant access to a hardcoded IP access for the EC2 instance. (*hard to maintain*)
- Grant access to an elastic IC address for the EC2 instance (*how?*)
- Grant full public access to the ES instance (*very insecure*)
- Send some sort of IAM/User credentials from Logstash to ES.

The last option would work, if I could figure out how to set it up.

---

**Edit**: Answer Syntax: based upon birryree's answer below, here's what I did to get this working:

- Add a new `command` to my `2_logstash.config` file (from the above blog post) in order to install the Amazon logstash plugin: `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-amazon_es`
- Tweak my `logstash` configuration file to use the `amazon_es` plugin. This was more or less a drop-in replacement for `elasticsearch`, though I did end up explicitly specifying the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic policy you have *should* work, a full policy granting permission to an IAM role looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/ROLE"
      },      
      "Action": "es:*", 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-1:ACCOUNT:domain/DOMAIN/*" 
    }   
  ] 
}
```

When you use an IAM role/user-based policy, however, you must send your Elasticsearch requests signed with [Version 4 Signatures](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). When you use the official AWS SDKs, they will transparently do the request signing when you access AWS ES resources.

Since you're using Logstash, though, the standard `logstash-elasticsearch` plugin doesn't support this, so if you want to minimize your exposure of who's allowed to access the ES cluster, then you probably want to use the AWS Logstash ES Output plugin.

Amazon AWS Labs have a plugin named [`logstash-output-amazon_es`](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es) which essentially behaves the exact same as `logstash_elasticsearch`, except it performs signing for each request.

This plugin does have some limitations, such as not supporting Logstash 5.x yet (it only supports Logstash v2.x). There is a year-old issue to merge the important bits into the official logstash plugin source, but it's unclear when that will actually happen.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. I'm adding some more detailed instructions for future readers in the original question.